# Debugging F# app using VSCode, WSL2 + Extensions (Ionide Packet, FAKE, Core)

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, f#, ionide

You're getting this error when trying to debug an F# app on VSCode using Ionide

```
Unable to launch debugger worker process (vsdbg) through the terminal. spawn xterm ENOENT
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Add a worskpace at the root folder of the app
   [image: enter image description hsere]
2. Add a debug config (launch.json) -> Select template .NET Core Launch (console)
3. Add a task for building the app -> You will be prompted to create this after you try to run the debugger following the previous step
4. Run from debugger

[image]

Here's my example config, same fields but using them from the workspace file instead of directly under .vscode/* (personal preference)

```
     {
      "folders": [
        {
          "path": "."
        }
      ],
      "settings": {},
      "launch": {
        "version": "0.2.0",
        "configurations": [
          {
            "name": ".NET Core Launch (console)",
            "type": "coreclr",
            "request": "launch",
            "preLaunchTask": "build",
// Change this path to point to your entrypoint
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/Debug/net6.0/hello-world.dll",
            "args": ["Hello"],
            "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
            "stopAtEntry": false,
            "console": "internalConsole"
          }
        ]
      },
      "tasks": {
        "version": "2.0.0",
        "tasks": [
          {
            "label": "build",
            "command": "dotnet",
            "type": "shell",
            "args": [
              "build",
              // Ask dotnet build to generate full paths for file names.
              "/property:GenerateFullPaths=true",
              // Do not generate summary otherwise it leads to duplicate errors in Problems panel
              "/consoleloggerparameters:NoSummary"
            ],
            "group": "build",
            "presentation": {
              "reveal": "silent"
            },
            "problemMatcher": "$msCompile"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```

Unfortunately, I haven't been able to run it from the Ionide tab. Please let me know if you know how to solve this on WS2.

[image]